# Can I use WCF tracing without config file?

Tags: wcf

In my WCF application, I have not used a config file in both client and server. I have created the address, binding and contract in code and used them to host the service and this is working fine. Now i want to add WCF tracing and I am not finding a way to add the tracing through code like below, where a config file is used:

```
<system.diagnostics>
  <sources>
     <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging">
       <listeners>
         <add name="messagelistener"
              type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
                     initializeData="d:\logs\myMessages.svclog"></add>
       </listeners>
     </source>
   </sources>
 </system.diagnostics>
 <system.serviceModel>
     <diagnostics>
       <messageLogging logEntireMessage="true"
                       logMessagesAtServiceLevel="false"
                       logMessagesAtTransportLevel="false"
                       logMalformedMessages="true"
                       maxMessagesToLog="5000"
                       maxSizeOfMessageToLog="2000">
       </messageLogging>
     </diagnostics>
 </system.serviceModel>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the official document about implementing this feature in code.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/samples/tracing-and-message-logging
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/debug-trace-profile/trace-listeners
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/diagnostics/configuring-message-logging

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"C:\1.mylog.svclog", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite);

        System.Diagnostics.Trace.Listeners.Clear();
        System.Diagnostics.Trace.Listeners.Add(new System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener(fs));
```

Besides, as far as I know, we can’t configure the WCF Message Logging in code. It only could be configured in the WebConfig.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/wcf/messagelogging
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I wanted to know the feasibility of doing that without a config file, and You have provided the answer correctly. This will help me.